# $\pm$ sign in electromagnetic wave ratio of $E$ and $B$ for regressive/progressive case

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electricity, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

I found on textbook that the magnitude of electric field $E$ and magnetic field $B$ in a plane electromagnetic wave are always related by the fact that

$$\frac{E}{B}=\pm v$$

Where $v$ is the velocity of wave and the $+$ sign is for **progressive** em wave, while the  $-$ sign is for **regressive** em wave.

It does not give much explanation for that $\pm$, how should this sign be interpreted?

Since $E$ and $B$ are in phase, they have the same sign in particular, therefore the ratio must be positive, so is the $-$ sign related to the fact that for regressive wave the velocity (component) is negative?

Otherwise, why the $\pm$?

Comment: Which textbook? What do you mean by 'progressive' and 'regressive' waves? And how do you define the scalar $E$ and $B$ amplitudes from the vector fields themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Overview

To my knowledge the terminology "progressive wave" and "regressive wave" is not common, and you can't count on working scientists recognizing it.

This appears to be a scheme to help you workout the relationship between the direction of the fields and the direction of wave propagation; in that it is equivalent to the cross-product
$$ \vec{S} = \vec{E} \times \vec{B} \tag{1} \;,$$
for the [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector).

#### Making sense of it

Let's say I know that a plane wave is propagating in free-space along the $z$ axis, but we don't know which way it is going. And that we know the polarization of the wave is such that electric field is along the $x$ axis.

If—at the time when $\vec{E} = +|E|\hat{x}$—I have

- $\vec{B} = +|B|\hat{y}$ then the wave is propagating in the $+\hat{z}$ direction (that is "progressive" in the language above)
- $\vec{B} = -|B|\hat{y}$ then the wave is propagating in the $-\hat{z}$ direction (that is "regressive" in the language above)

In other works, by aligning the ray and fields on the axes we can write $E = E_x(t)$ and $B = B_y(t)$ and the ratio that you exhibit can then have either sign *even for a free-space wave that is in-phase*.

#### Suggestion

The relationship is better understood in terms of the cross-product in equation (1) than in the baroque structure offered by the book you are reading. If only because the cross-product is already generalized to non-axis-aligned propagation.

Answer (score 0):

This would be true only for propagation in lossless media.  Moreover, since we are discussing magnitudes the $-$ sign does not make sense.

In general the ratio $E/H$ is related to the impedance $\eta$ of the medium in which the wave propagates.  This impedance is complex in general but real for lossless media (for which the conductivity $\sigma=0$.)  When $\eta$ is complex, $\vec E$ and $\vec H$ need not be in phase: the maxima of $E$ and $H$ are shifted, with the shift related to the argument of $\eta$, but this phase-shift is time-independent.

For propagation in a lossless medium we have
$$
H=\frac{E}{\eta}=\frac{B}{\mu}\, .
$$

In vacuum $\eta=\sqrt{\mu_0/\epsilon_0}\approx 377\Omega$ and $\mu=\mu_0=4\pi\times 10^{-7}$.  Thus
$$
\frac{E}{B}=\frac{\eta_0}{\mu_0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}}=c
$$
which would generalize to $v=1/\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}$ for another lossless medium.

Comment: Although I have not seen it myself am just wondering if somebody might employ such sign convention to represent left/right circular polarization or some such?

Comment: That would not have much to do with amplitudes, and since the direction of propagation (in a lossless media) in perpendicular to $\vec E$ and $\vec H$ I can't see a connection.  The statement about $E/B=\pm \nu$ is decidedly strange as we have little context for it.